# Guide to setting up Fluent NHibernate from File - New Project

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to create a new project, and I want to use NHibernate (specifically Fluent NHibernate).

My biggest problem learning a new technology is just getting it set up, and I'm having a lot of difficulties with this. I started out looking at this (http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-1.aspx#download-fluent-nhibernate), but it seems outdated, as I also looked at this (http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Installation), and they had different binaries.

There are several other guides, but most assume that you have NHiberate in your project already, and it's only a guide to set up Fluent NHibernate.

Any simple guides out there that will help you set it up, starting from the very beginning with File - New Project?

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm using .NET 4.0 and MVC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at [**NuGet**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_n7vwoKVDo&feature=player_embedded). This takes over the admittedly gruesome job of setting up NHibernate for the first time (and many other packages!).

With NuGet, setting up binaries should be [**as simple**](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/748_Introduction_to_NuGet.aspx) as

```
add-package nhibernate.core
```

- [NuGet on CodePlex](http://nuget.codeplex.com/)
- [Introduction to NuGet](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/748_Introduction_to_NuGet.aspx)
- [NHibernate - Learning with code samples](http://www.fincher.org/tips/Languages/NHibernate.shtml)